# Erroneous code diagnostics report in RStudio when sourcing functions via source

Tags: r, rstudio, environment, scoping

I'm working in [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) on a simple analysis where I source some files via the `source` command. For example, I have this file with some simple analysis:

## analysis.R

```
# Settings ----------------------------------------------------------------

data("mtcars")
source("Generic Functions.R")

# Some work ---------------------------------------------------------------

# Makes no sense
mtcars$mpg <- CleanPostcode(mtcars$mpg)
```

The *generic functions* file has some simple functions that I use to derive graphs and do repetitive tasks. For example the used CleanPostcode function would look like that:

## Generic Functions.R

```
#' The file provides a set of generic functions 

# String manipulations ----------------------------------------------------

# Create a clean Postcode for matching
CleanPostcode <- function(MessyPostcode) {
  MessyPostcode <- as.character(MessyPostcode)
  MessyPostcode <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", MessyPostcode)
  MessyPostcode <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", MessyPostcode)
  MessyPostcode <- toupper(MessyPostcode)
  cln_str <- MessyPostcode
  return(cln_str)
}
```

When I run the first file, the objects are available in the global environment:

[image: Global environment]

*There are some other function in the file but they are not relevant to the described problem.*

Nevertheless the RStudio sees the object as not available in scope, as illustrated by the yellow triangle next to the code:

[image: problem]

## Question

Is there a way to make RStudio stop doing that. Maybe changing something to the `source` command? I tried `local = TRUE` and got the same thing. The code works with no problems, I just find it annoying.

---

*The report was generated on the **version 0.99.491** of RStudio.*